# Profile applications from traffic analysis

Tags: firewalls, network-scanners, risk-management, monitoring, packet

I'm investigating options for segmenting a less secure business unit behind a Cisco 5505. I want to take this action quietly and transparently for political reasons.

I want to know if it is possible to feed traffic analysis into some kind of engine to parse out a whitelist of applications and ports. E.G. load a few day's worth of pcapng files and get back a list of "IP.src, IP.dst, Port, Application name". Are there any tools for that kind of profiling?

Comment: wireshark does exactly this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Wireshark to extract conversation statistics from the packet captures.  This information can then be sorted through to determine which ports are used regularly:

[image: Wireshark Conversation Statistics]

This screen is from the Wireshark Statistics->Conversations menu items.  It also has a "Copy" button which will allow you to get this data as CSV; you could then extract destination ports simply:

```
gawk -F, '{print $4}' convo.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

or do more complex analysis based on source and destination.  Personally, if I were doing it, I'd load the CSV into a sqlite database for ease of querying seven ways from Sunday.

You can also automate the extraction of the conversation statistics [by using tshark](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/13096/how-to-get-statistics-conversation-list-tcp-information-in-a-text-file) to cut your workload - less clicky clicky, more worky worky.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your question well enough, but to me this sounds like all you really want is to open the pcapng-file(s) in [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Maybe my answer is totally off the track. If this is the case, please specify your question further.

Comment: That would work, but my problem is combing through days of data manually. I was hoping to get a summary output rather than burn my time noting each unique flow. It's a large and unnecessarily complex business unit, so I'm hoping to cut workload where possible.

Comment: @AlexCosby Wireshark provides summaries.

Comment: hmmm. i don't have much time investigating that right now, but there are a bunch of tools shipping with wireshark. Maybe have a look here - i doubt that wireshark doesn't supply the methods you need natively! 
https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools

the hard way would be offcourse to write a parsing/extracting script yourself, if this is an option.